# Store Django form.cleaned_data in null model field?

Tags: python, django

I have a django model, which has a int field (with null=True, blank=True).
Now when I get a form submit from the user, I assign it like so:

```
my_model.width= form.cleaned_data['width']
```

However sometimes I get an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I was wandering if it's the blank ('') string value that gets assigned to the field?
Because my understanding was the model will treat blank string as null/blank?

Any help would be appreciated in this matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't. If you want to assign NULL, use Python's `None`. Otherwise Django will try to parse a number from the string and that fails for the empty string.

You can use the `or` construct to achieve this:

```
my_model.width = form.cleaned_data['width'] or None
```

Comment: A good place to do this would be a clean_width function of form.